.NET MAUI Community Toolkit Popup page is breaking
I am using the .NET Community toolkit for the Popup page. When we try to load the popup page the entire UI is breaking on iOS platform but it is working fine on Android platform. On the popup page I am using listView.
Screenshot:
iOS platform:

I am using below codes to open the pop up page:
this.ShowPopup(new FilterRequestPopupPage("ViewRequestsPage"));

PopUp Page Sample Code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converter" 
    Color="Transparent"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    x:Class="ListPMCaller.Views.Requests.FilterRequestPopupPage">

    <Border
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        x:Name="requeststatus_layout"
        Margin="15,0"
        Stroke="#e6e6e6"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20"
        Padding="0">

        <StackLayout
            Orientation="Vertical">

            <ListView
                VerticalOptions="Start"
                x:Name="requestfilter_listview"
                SeparatorColor="#cecece"
                ItemTapped="requestfilter_listview_ItemTapped"
                SelectionMode="None"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout 
                                Padding="5"
                                Margin="5"
                                Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label 
                                    Text="{Binding statusTitle, Converter={StaticResource specialCharactorConverter}}"
                                    TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"
                                    Style="{StaticResource UserNameLabelStyle}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.Footer>
                    <Label/>
                </ListView.Footer>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </Border>
</toolkit:Popup>

Can you please provide me with a solution to resolve this issue? The issue is only on iOS platform.
Update
I have created a sample project and uploaded it here. Click on any option to view the next page and their top right select the icon to view the popup.
Current UI:

Expected UI:


Please post some relevant code how you display the Popup to help us reproduce this issue. And did it throw any exception?

@LiqunShen-MSFT I have added sample codes of pop up page and no exception is throwing.

Do you mean showing the Popup causes the underlying Layout confused?  Is it a StackLayout or Grid?

@LiqunShen-MSFT When I open pop up page, the UI is breaking like this. We are using Border as the parent layout of pop up page, I have added codes for that in question.

@MatthewPans You have "VerticalStackLayout" with vertically unrestricted child. Set HeightRequest=100 to the ListView and test. Now when I got a closer look at your code - you are not even using it for anything... Remove the stack from the hierarchy.

@H.A.H. I tried this solution, but it is not working for the popup page

@MatthewPans Slap HeightRequest=100 to the border AND the ListView. And remove the stack. And remove the viewcell from the template, and set request to the stack of the template.

@H.A.H. I tried this solution, and there is no change to the PopUp page.

Your Popup code works well on my side. From the screenshot, I see the Back button, My Requests and some controls in confusion. Does  this Popup page mess up the underlying page?

@LiqunShen-MSFT Yes, the popup page mess up the underlying page. I have updated the question with more details.

That's really weird. The underlying page of Android and iOS seems totally different.. Maybe we should figure it out step by step. Do you use .NET8 and the latest Community Toolkit? Also, it would be much better if you could share the relevant code for the underlying page.

@LiqunShen-MSFT We are using the .NET 7 and not the latest Community Toolkit. We try to install the latest version of Community Toolkit but we get an error. The error: Could not install the latest Community Toolkit .

That's because you use .NET7. Never mind. But i also try using .NET7 and CommunityToolkit 6.1.0. Still, nothing wrong with your Popup code.

Is this because of the underlying page? If you simplify the underlying page, will this issue happen? Or if you could post us more relevant code to help us reproduce it.

@LiqunShen-MSFT  We have added a sample project on the question, could you please check that?

Of course. But seems something wrong with the link.  In order to protect your privacy, please do not share your complete project. Also Remember to remove any personal privacy information in the sample.

@LiqunShen-MSFT The link working properly from our side. Can you share what is the issue.

Cannot reproduce this issue using .NET7 and CommunityToolkit.Maui 6.1.0  on iPhone 15 pro max sumulator (iOS17.2). Click option1  and then click ic_filter_xx.png,  then Popup pops and works fine. Did i miss anything?

@LiqunShen-MSFT Could you share the pop up page that you are receiving on your side? Like we posted on the question a broken image we are getting. https://i.sstatic.net/pBEx9tzf.png

Workaround
You could update CommunityToolkit.Maui to version 6.1.0 (Since you are using .NET7). Though we recommend you update the MAUI App to use .NET8

Cannot reproduce this issue using .NET7 and CommunityToolkit.Maui 6.1.0 on iPhone 15 pro max sumulator (iOS17.2).
Here is the screenshot I get,


But we are getting the below UI as the output. https://i.sstatic.net/YjzRuRUx.png Do u have any idea why this is happening?

I think I may find  the issue, Just update your CommunityToolkit.Maui  to  6.1.0  and have a try.

It resolved the issue, please include it on your answer.
